# Disable CSS merge via URL GET parameter

Tags: magento-1.9, css, development

is there a way to disable CSS merge via URL GET parameter or something like this?
I want to keep the merged CSS files for customers while i want to get unmerged version to do some testings for the customer.

Yes i know, i should always do tests on a development machine. Problem is, the development machine is already 1.9.2.3 while the live shop is 1.7.x and we've done a --force update while the customer or the previous agency of the customer did changes in the extensions CSS original file.

Comment: do you have using default magento css merge

Comment: yes. but it's no option to turn it off in live at customers request.

Comment: `turn it off in live at customers request. ` mean?

Comment: That the customer doesn't allow to turn of merge on live system in general. Therefore my question was, if there is some kind of e.g. URL GET paramter that will deliver the non-merged version. It also could be some kind of combination with dev mode or so on. But customers should get shipped with merged version.